# NetworkStream.Read() doesn't work and throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server, chat

Just trying to create a chat server-client

1. This is the server waiting for a client connection (optional)*

   ```
       TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
       int requestCount = 0;
       TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
       serverSocket.Start();
       Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
       clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
       Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
   ```
2. Then, the client connects to the server (optional)*

   ```
       System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
       clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
   ```
3. Then, on the client side, I send the message from a windows form, and the button click event does this:

   ```
   NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
   byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
   serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
   serverStream.Flush();
   //this goes to the server  ------> to the part (4)

   //returning from the server <------
   byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
   serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
   string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
   textBox2.Text = "";
   textBox2.Focus();
   ```
4. Finally, on the server side, an infinite bucle for client requests. And here is where I got the problem on the networkStream.Read()

   ```
   while ((true))
       {
           try
           {
               requestCount = requestCount + 1;
               NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
               byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
               if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
               {
                   **networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int) clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);**
                   string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                   dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                   Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                   string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;
                   Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                   networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                   networkStream.Flush();
                   Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
           }
       }
   ```

I debugged step by step (on server and client), and it's all fine until I get to the networkStream.Read() method, and throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException...  Please, anybody help me or tell me where the error is.

*I say optional because the 1. and 2. steps are fine (at least, I think)

Comment: You should pass `bytesFrom.Length` instead of `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` to `networkStream.Read`.

Comment: What is the value of `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1), ArgumentOutOfRangeException means that *offset* or *count* is negative(2nd and 3rd parameters), OR the "size(count)" parameter is greater than the length of buffer minus the value of the "offset" parameter.

I'd try passing `bytesFrom.Length` as opposed to `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`.