# c# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in TCP connect

Tags: c#, tcp

i want to make a program who chat with TCP.

When i try to connect the client to the server, it crash and error :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

D'ont know how to solve this exception.

code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    int counter = 0;

    serverSocket.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
    counter = 0;
    while ((true))
    {
        counter += 1;
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;

        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

        clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

        broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

        Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
        handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
        client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
    }

    clientSocket.Close();
    serverSocket.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

in the line

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Comment: This question already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682574/1102741

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful